# Won't run the class, Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I was following a book on to learn java when it told me to enter this code:

```
package com.thekyle.hi;

class Myclass {
    int x;

    Myclass(int i) {
        x = i;
    }
}

class ParmsConsDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Myclass t1 = new Myclass(10);
        Myclass t2 = new Myclass(88);
        System.out.println(t1.x + " " + t2.x);

    }
}// OutPut is 10 88
```

And it will launch a different class than this one. How do I make it launch?

Comment: if you are running on eclipse...right click program -> run as -> java application

Comment: What is the file name of your source file? If it is not `ParmsConsDemo.java`, then rename it to it, and make that class public also. (And - please - it is `String[] args` and not `String args[]`, although Java allows that.)

Comment: Nope it says only "run configurations"

Comment: When I rename it to the Source Folder it says it is already defined, The Type Example is Already defined.And when I add Public it gives me, delete this token error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this as follows

1. First, you need make sure the java file name has the same as your class name. see the red circle in the screen shot below.

[image]

2. Right click on your source code. Run As> Run Configurations... then in Run configuration pop up window, you need make sure that it is filled up with the right project name and Main class name, which is ParmsConsDemo in your case. see the screen shot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make `ParmsConsDemo` public.

```
...
public class ParmsConsDemo {
 ...
  public static void main(String[] args){
    ..
  }
...
}
```

Comment: This is my first thought also, but amazingly, you don't need to make it public  :)